# Can not connect to SMB after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs, smb

I have 3 locations in file managers　previously in 17.10.

After upgrading to 18.04, they are not working anymore,

`error: Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out`

Then I tried to manually mount them:

`sudo mount.cifs //****/**** /mnt/share -o username=***, domain=***,vers=1.0`

Error: 
`mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Then I tried to check `tail -f  /var/log/kern.log`, it shows:`CIFS VFS: Malformed UNC in devname.`

How do I solve it?

Comment: I had the same problem. Is the share a DFS? The problem is that somehow cifs cannot follow the softlinks... What I did to solve the problem was to get the absolute path of every folder contained in the DFS and mounted them separately. You can get the target by mounting your DFS in windows and then via Right-click on one link/properties/DFS Tab

Comment: I had issues too, but it was fine when I added `-o username=xx,password=yy,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777`  (some like vers=1.0 were added in 17.10 or earlier, and your device(s) may not need all of these).   Note: you have a SPACE before ,domain=*** - space is a delimeter!

Comment: Same problem. I have to reboot, then I can access the samba shares with Files. But after a while I get the Invalid Argument message.